# If the user has this role, so display the message. How to do it? Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

If the user has this role, so display the message.
But nothing works and this is part of my code:

```
role_girl = 72850048118554 #ID ROLE
role_boy = 72849957361759 #ID ROLE
role_nonepol = 72850091485547 #ID ROLE

@client.command( aliases = [ 'test' ] )
async def __test( ctx, member: discord.Member ):

    if role_girl in member.roles:
        preff = ' youre a girl '

    if role_boy in member.roles:
        preff = ' youre a boy '

    if role_nonepol in member.roles:
        preff = ' is not specified '

    await ctx.send( f'{ member.mention } { preff }' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.roles` returns a list of classes so you need to specify if you want the role name or id.
 You can do it two ways:

- By comparing each roles with your IDs:

```py
role_girl = 72850048118554
role_boy = 72849957361759
role_nonepol = 72850091485547

@client.command( aliases = [ 'test' ] )
async def __test( ctx, member: discord.Member ):
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.id == role_girl:
            preff = ' youre a girl '
        elif role.id == role_boy:
            preff = ' youre a boy '
        elif role.id == role_nonepol:
            preff = ' is not specified '

    await ctx.send( f'{ member.mention } { preff }' )
```

- By checking if the user has a role with the `get` method (you'll have to replace name="..." with the exact role name):

```py
from discord.utils import get

@client.command( aliases = [ 'test' ] )
async def __test( ctx, member: discord.Member ):
    if get(member.roles, name='girl'):
        preff = ' youre a girl '
    elif get(member.roles, name='boy'):
        preff = ' youre a boy '
    elif get(member.roles, name='nonpol'):
        preff = ' is not specified '

    await ctx.send( f'{ member.mention } { preff }' )
```